# I want to restrict access to a web app created with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

#### What we want to achieve

If a user other than the user who accessed with the specified google account accesses the site, we want to restrict access.

#### Assumptions

I wrote the following code.
However, access was not allowed for users other than the deployed account.
Even if I access with the specified account, I get the message "You do not have access permission.

```
function doGet() {
// google account to allow access
var allowedEmails = ["xxxx1@gmail.com", "xxxx2@gmail.com", "xxxx3@gmail.com"];

// get google account of user accessing
var LOGIN_USER = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

if (!allowedEmails.includes(LOGIN_USER)) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>You do not have access permission<p>);
  }
}
```

#### Deployment Configuration

- Run as the following user
  Myself (xxxx1@gmail.com)
- Users with access
  "Everyone with a Google account".

#### What we tried

```
var htmlContent ='<p>Email address of user accessing: ' + LOGIN_USER + '</p>';
```

I tried this to see if I could get the email address,
I got a blank.

Perhaps it is not working.
I think the cause is this part.

Comment: How about putting it on a  shared drive and only give access to certain users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Change the Configuration to "User accessing the web app"

Based from your deployment configuration, you only ran the web app as `Me (email address)`. This will not work for other users who are trying to access your web app. Instead, use `Execute as: User Accessing the web app`

[image]

With this, the other users will be prompted with:
[image]

The other users should allow the permissions in order to access your web app.

### Test Case

I used the following script to check:

```
function doGet() {
  var data = ["patrick*******@gmail.com"];
  if(data.includes(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
  }
  else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() + " -  not allowed");
  }
}
```

And got the following output for `with access`:

[image]

and `without access`:

[image]

### Reference:

- [Web Apps - Permission](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#:%7E:text=Execute%20the%20app%20as%20user,when%20the%20user%20authorizes%20access.)